# Split thousands of columns at a time by '/' on multiple lines, sort the values in the new rows and add 'NA' values

Tags: r, split

I would like to split a data frame with thousands of columns. The data frame looks like this:

```
# sample data of four columns
sample <-read.table(stdin(),header=TRUE,sep="")
POS v1  v2  v3  v4
152 0   0/1 0/2 0/1/2
73  1   0   0/1 0/1
185 0   1   0/3 0
```

THe output should be:

```
POS v1  v2  v3  v4
152 0   0   0   0
152 NA  1   NA  1
152 NA  NA  2   2
73  NA  0   0   0
73  1   NA  1   1
185 0   NA  0   0
185 NA  1   NA  NA
185 NA  NA  NA  NA
185 NA  NA  3   NA
```

The values ​​0, 1, 2 and 3 should be ordered on the new lines thus obtained, while the value in the field POS should be repeated. Then NA value should be inserted to obtain the same length colums.

Comment: do you primarily need it to *work* or primary to work *fast*?  have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I assume 0/1/2 is always in-order.

Comment: Also, WHY do you need this - for instance would transformation into a bitfield not be just as effective? (and also much much faster)

Comment: Is it important that 185 has an NA row corresponding to 2 but 73 does not?

Comment: please provide a sample function to read in the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
dt <- data.table(df)
fun <- function(DT) {
  split <- strsplit(vapply(DT, as.character, character(1L)), "/")
  lapply(split, 
    function(x, max.len) as.numeric(x)[match(0:max.len, as.numeric(x))],
    max.len=max(as.numeric(unlist(split)))
) }
dt[, fun(.SD), by=POS]
#    POS v1 v2 v3 v4
# 1: 152  0  0  0  0
# 2: 152 NA  1 NA  1
# 3: 152 NA NA  2  2
# 4:  73 NA  0  0  0
# 5:  73  1 NA  1  1
# 6: 185  0 NA  0  0
# 7: 185 NA  1 NA NA
# 8: 185 NA NA NA NA
# 9: 185 NA NA  3 NA
```

The idea is to use `data.table` to execute our function `fun` against the data elements of each row (i.e. excluding `POS`).  `data.table` will stitch back `POS` for our modified result.

Here `fun` starts by converting each data row to a character vector, and then splitting by `/`, which will produce a list with for each item, a character vector with as many elements as there were `/`, + 1.

Finally, `lapply` cycles through each of these list items, converting them all to the same length vectors, filling in with `NA`, and sorting.

`data.table` recognizes the resulting list as representing columns for our result set, and adds back the `POS` column as noted earlier.

---

EDIT: the following addresses a question in the comments:

```
val <- "0/2/3:25:0.008,0.85,0.002:0.004,0.013,0.345"
first.colon <- strsplit(val, ":")[[1]][[1]]
strsplit(first.colon, "/")[[1]]
// [1] "0" "2" "3"
```

The key thing to understand is `strsplit` returns a list with as many elements as there are items in your input vector.  In this toy example there is only one item in the vector, so there is only one item in the list, though each item is a character vector that can have multiple values (in this case, 3 after we split by `/`).  So something like this should work (but I haven't tested debugged):

```
dt <- data.table(df)
fun <- function(DT) {
  split <- strsplit(vapply(DT, as.character, character(1L)), ":")
  split.2 <- vapply(split, `[[`, character(1L), 1)  # get just first value from `:` split
  split.2 <- strsplit(split.2, "/")
  lapply(split.2, 
    function(x, max.len) as.numeric(x)[match(0:max.len, as.numeric(x))],
    max.len=max(as.numeric(unlist(split)))
) }
```

Comment: If in v1:v4 there are not numbers but a string as.character    '0/2/3:25:0.008,0.85,0.002:0.004,0.013,0.345', I'd have first to split it by ':', then select only the first element and split it by '/'. How can I select the element of the list after the splitting?

Answer (score 3):

```
tmp <- apply(sample[-1], 1, function(x) {
  s <- strsplit(x, "\\/")
  num <- lapply(s, as.integer)
  ma <- max(unlist(num))
  vec <- rep(NA_integer_, ma + 1)
  sapply(num, function(y) replace(vec, y + 1, y)) 
})

res <- data.frame(POS = rep(sample[[1]], sapply(tmp, nrow)),
                  do.call(rbind, tmp))

#   POS v1 v2 v3 v4
# 1 152  0  0  0  0
# 2 152 NA  1 NA  1
# 3 152 NA NA  2  2
# 4  73 NA  0  0  0
# 5  73  1 NA  1  1
# 6 185  0 NA  0  0
# 7 185 NA  1 NA NA
# 8 185 NA NA NA NA
# 9 185 NA NA  3 NA
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the interesting data is really a matrix

```
m = as.matrix(sample[,-1])
```

The underlying data is then a vector with relatively few unique values; we'll map the unique values to their integer representation, using the map where possible to minimize the number of iterations in any loops that are necessary

```
s = as.character(m)
map = lapply(strsplit(setNames(unique(s), unique(s)), "/"), as.integer)
```

Here's the number of times each row needs to be replicated

```
row.len = apply(matrix(sapply(map, max)[s], ncol=ncol(m)), 1, max) + 1
```

and the offsets into `s` of each row

```
offset = head(c(1, cumsum(rep(row.len, ncol(m))) + 1), -1)
```

Calculate the values of each mapped element, and the index of the value in `s`

```
v = unlist(unname(map)[match(s, names(map))])
idx = rep(offset, sapply(map, length)[s]) + v
```

Finally, allocate the result matrix of NA's, and update the non-NA values

```
ans = matrix(NA_integer_, sum(row.len), ncol(m))
ans[idx] = v
```

As a function:

```
flatten <- function(sample) {
    m = as.matrix(sample[,-1])
    s = as.character(m)
    map = lapply(strsplit(setNames(unique(s), unique(s)), "/"), as.integer)
    row.len = apply(matrix(sapply(map, max)[s], ncol=ncol(m)), 1, max) + 1
    offset = head(c(1, cumsum(rep(row.len, ncol(m))) + 1), -1)
    v = unlist(unname(map)[match(s, names(map))])
    idx = rep(offset, sapply(map, length)[s]) + v
    ans = matrix(NA_integer_, sum(row.len), ncol(m),
        dimnames=list(NULL, colnames(sample)[-1]))
    ans[idx] = v
    cbind(POS=rep(sample[,1], row.len), as.data.frame(ans))
}
```

The slowest part of this will be the `apply` function for calculating `row.len`.  Some timing (I guess the dimensions are not correct for the problem...)

```
xx = do.call(rbind, replicate(10000, sample, simplify=FALSE))
dim(xx)
## [1] 30000     5
system.time(flatten(xx))
##   user  system elapsed 
##  0.192   0.000   0.194
```

versus about 5s for the data.table solution above.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution that instead of generating multiple rows, generates a bit mask for each value indicating presence or absence of the "0" "1" "2" etc bit.

```
> sample <-read.table(stdin(),header=TRUE,sep="",
                          row.names=1,colClasses="character")
0: POS v1  v2  v3  v4
1: 152 0   0/1 0/2 0/1/2
2: 73  1   0   0/1 0/1
3: 185 0   1   0/3 0
4: 
> # transform the strings into bit masks
> B<-function(X)lapply(strsplit(X,"/"),
                function(n)Reduce(bitOr,bitwShiftL(1,as.numeric(n)),0))
> B("0/1")
[[1]]
[1] 3
> # apply it everywhere
> s<-colwise(B)(sample)
> rownames(s)<-rownames(sample)
> s
    v1 v2 v3 v4
152  1  3  5  7
73   2  1  3  3
185  1  2  9  1
```

While it's not what you asked for, assuming the set of enum values is small (0,1,2) it is much much more efficient in storage space and can be processed easily:

Which elements have v1 "0" and v3 "0" and "1"

```
> subset(s, bitAnd(v1,B("0")) & bitAnd(v4,B("0/1")))
    v1 v2 v3 v4
152  1  3  5  7
185  1  2  9  1
```

Comment: I was hoping to find some way to project the 2 dimensional data frame (as a matrix) into a 3 dimensions form with T/F where values existed, but I couldn't easily work out how.  This would be the dense equivalent of the sparse representation he requested.