# Creating seperate data.frame rows for each one of multiple values in a column

Tags: r, dataframe

Sorry about the ineloquent Title!

Some currencies are used by more than one country

I have a table which combines the countries in one column

```
df<- data.frame(code=c("DKK","DZD","EGP"), country=c("Denmark, Faroe Islands, Greenland",
                                                    "Algeria","Egypt,Palestinian territories"))

  code                           country
1  DKK Denmark, Faroe Islands, Greenland
2  DZD                           Algeria
3  EGP     Egypt,Palestinian territories
```

I would like to seperate this combined field so that I end up with

```
  code                 country
1  DKK                 Denmark
2  DKK           Faroe Islands
3  DKK               Greenland
4  DZD                 Algeria
5  EGP                   Egypt
6  EGP Palestinian territories
```

TIA

Comment: See [this very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124838/split-thousands-of-columns-at-a-time-by-on-multiple-lines-sort-the-values-i).

Comment: Something like `strsplit` would work well here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 3 possibilities. One using only native R:

```
endresult = do.call("rbind",by(df,df$code, 
function(x) { data.frame(cbind(as.character(x$code),
              unlist(strsplit(paste(x$country,collapse=","),",")[[1]]))) } ))
rownames(endresult) = NULL
```

or:

```
tf = by(df$country,df$code,function(x) strsplit(paste(x,collapse=","),",")[[1]] )
endresult = do.call("rbind",lapply(names(tf),function(x) { vals=tf[x][[1]]; data.frame("code"=rep(x,length(vals)),"country"=vals ) } ))
```

Another using plyr:

```
require(plyr)
endresult = ddply(df, "code", 
                  function(x) { cbind(as.character(x$code),
                  unlist(strsplit(paste(x$country,collapse=","),",")[[1]])) } )
```

I am sure there are plenty more ways to be found.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Just the ticket

Comment: No prob. The paste-collapse is there in case you have multiple "code" entries in the same frame. if you want to get rid of duplicate "country" entries you will need to use `duplicated` at the end.