# Split different lengths values and bind to columns

Tags: r, data.table, rbind, strsplit

I've got a rather large (around 100k observations) data set, similar to this:

```
data <- data.frame(
                 ID = seq(1, 5, 1),
                 Values = c("1,2,3", "4", " ", "4,1,6,5,1,1,6", "0,0"), 
                 stringsAsFactors=F)
data
  ID        Values
1  1         1,2,3
2  2             4
3  3              
4  4 4,1,6,5,1,1,6
5  5           0,0
```

I want to split the Values column by `","` with `NA` for missed cells:

```
ID v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7
1  1  2  3  NA NA NA NA
2  4  NA NA NA NA NA NA
3  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
4  4  1  6  5  1  1  6
5  0  0  NA NA NA NA NA
...
```

Best attempt was `strsplit` + `rbind`:

```
df <- data.frame(do.call(
                        "rbind",
                        strsplit(as.character(data$Values), split = "," , fixed = FALSE)
                        ))
```

But `rbind` function just recycles all 'short' rows instead to set an "NA".
[Have found similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124838/split-thousands-of-columns-at-a-time-by-on-multiple-lines-sort-the-values-i)

Many thanks, Leo

Comment: +1 for reproducible question with desired results and demonstrating what you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest looking at [my `cSplit` function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733) or approaching the problem manually.

The `cSplit` approach would simply be:

```
cSplit(data, "Values", ",")
#    ID Values_1 Values_2 Values_3 Values_4 Values_5 Values_6 Values_7
# 1:  1        1        2        3       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2:  2        4       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 3:  3                NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 4:  4        4        1        6        5        1        1        6
# 5:  5        0        0       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

Approaching the problem manually would look like:

```
## Split up the values
Split <- strsplit(data$Values, ",", fixed = TRUE)
## How long is each list element?
Ncol <- vapply(Split, length, 1L)
## Create an empty character matrix to store the results
M <- matrix(NA_character_, nrow = nrow(data),
            ncol = max(Ncol), 
            dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("V", sequence(max(Ncol)))))
## Use matrix indexing to figure out where to put the results
M[cbind(rep(1:nrow(data), Ncol), 
        sequence(Ncol))] <- unlist(Split, use.names = FALSE)
## Bind the values back together, here as a "data.table" (faster)
data.table(ID = data$ID, M)
```

^^ That's pretty much what goes on in `cSplit`, but the function has a few other options and some basic error checking and so on that might make it a little bit slower than a purely manual approach (or a function written to address your specific problem).

Both of these approaches would be faster than a "data.table" + "reshape2" approach. Also, since each row is treated individually, you shouldn't have any problems even if you have duplicated ID values--your output should have the same number of rows as your input.

---

#### Benchmarks

I've done benchmarks on more rows and on data that would give "wider" results (since that's implied in your comments to David's answer).

Here is the sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
a <- sample(0:100, 100000, TRUE)
Values <- vapply(a, function(x) 
  paste(sample(0:100, x, TRUE), collapse = ","), character(1L))
Values[sample(length(Values), length(Values) * .15)] <- ""
ID <- c(1:80000, 1:20000)
data <- data.frame(ID, Values, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DT <- as.data.table(data)
```

Here are the functions to test:

```
fun1a <- function(inDT) {
  data2 <- DT[, list(Values = unlist(
    strsplit(Values, ","))), by = ID]
  data2[, Var := paste0("v", seq_len(.N)), by = ID] 
  dcast.data.table(data2, ID ~ Var, 
                   fill = NA_character_, 
                   value.var = "Values")
}

fun1b <- function(inDT) {
  data2 <- DT[, list(Values = unlist(
    strsplit(Values, ",", fixed = TRUE), 
    use.names = FALSE)), by = ID]
  data2[, Var := paste0("v", seq_len(.N)), by = ID] 
  dcast.data.table(data2, ID ~ Var, 
                   fill = NA_character_, 
                   value.var = "Values")
}

fun2 <- function(inDT) {
  cSplit(DT, "Values", ",")
}

fun3 <- function(inDF) {
  Split <- strsplit(inDF$Values, ",", fixed = TRUE)
  Ncol <- vapply(Split, length, 1L)
  M <- matrix(NA_character_, nrow = nrow(inDF),
              ncol = max(Ncol), 
              dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("V", sequence(max(Ncol)))))
  M[cbind(rep(1:nrow(inDF), Ncol), 
          sequence(Ncol))] <- unlist(Split, use.names = FALSE)
  data.table(ID = inDF$ID, M)
}
```

Here are the results:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun2(DT), fun3(data), times = 20)
# Unit: seconds
#        expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#    fun2(DT) 4.810942 5.173103 5.498279 5.622279 6.003339    20
#  fun3(data) 3.847228 3.929311 4.058728 4.160082 4.664568    20

## Didn't want to microbenchmark here...
system.time(fun1a(DT))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   16.92    0.50   17.59
system.time(fun1b(DT))  # fixed = TRUE & use.names = FALSE
#    user  system elapsed 
#   11.54    0.42   12.01
```

NOTE: The results of `fun1a` and `fun1b` would not be the same as those of `fun2` and `fun3` because of the duplicated IDs.

Comment: I can agree that `cSplit` will be faster, but I don't think it will reach the desired output just with that line. Re the `vapply` + `sequence`, I'm not sure they will be so fast as both basically `for` loops. Did you benchmark on a big data set?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, what would be missing? Just the column names? Or am I misreading the question? I'll be back with some benchmarks.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, while my benchmarks run, it's not `vapply` where I'm expecting the speed, but the matrix indexing stuff....

Comment: Ok, I take that back re `cSplit`. It seems like it's doing exactly what he needs. I was thinking of using it, but was to lazy to find the gist Id. You really need to work with @Arun on adding it to the `data.table` package

Comment: cSplit works fantastic! I don't even need to add additional column with unique IDs. Also there is a better column names, than in DT+Reshape2. Thank you so much for your help DavidArenburg, @AnandaMahto. I'm really appreciate. R is awesome!

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, I tried too long to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `data.table` combined with `reshape2` approach (should be very efficient)

```
library(data.table) # Loading `data.table` package
data2 <- setDT(data)[, list(Values = unlist(strsplit(Values, ","))), by = ID] # splitting the values by `,` for each `ID`
data2[, Var := paste0("v", seq_len(.N)), by = ID] # Adding the `Var` variable

library(reshape2) # Loading `reshape2` package
dcast.data.table(data2, ID ~ Var, fill = NA_character_, value.var = "Values") # decasting

#    ID v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7
# 1:  1  1  2  3 NA NA NA NA
# 2:  2  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 3:  3    NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 4:  4  4  1  6  5  1  1  6
# 5:  5  0  0 NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: Sorry for this mess. Of course it should have 7 columns.

Comment: Thanks, @David Arenburg, it works well, but what if ID isn't unique?

Comment: `ID` is unique. I don't understand your question. I reached your desired output exactly

Comment: In my real data there is some strings with equal ID. I think I'm a bit hurried, before sending a question

Comment: So? This should still work. I'm using `by = ID` in the code, so it will work

Comment: Main data got 90180x2 dimension and the dcast 6867x4490.

Comment: Maybe the `ID` column in your data isn't unique? Try `tail(sort(table(data$ID)), 10)` for example

Comment: Yes, it isn't unique, and it shouldn't be. I did not think about it when I made the question, because I did not realize that it is important.

Comment: @Leo, you want your output to have the same number of rows as the input, right? That shouldn't be too hard to fix (just add another id column) but there are some faster options for you to consider.